# How do I redirect to the register page instead of the login?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

This is what I want to achieve: Click a product -> Register -> Checkout
I have a page where you select the a product, and I have the all the product links go to the `checkout` controller and pass a parameter via URL. e.g. `domain.com/checkout/product-name`.

However, I want the user to be logged in before using the checkout controller, so naturally, I denied it with `$this->Auth->deny('index')` in the `beforeFilter()` of the checkout controller. Now, when I try to access the checkout controller, it redirects me to the login page. Is there a way for me to have it go to the register page instead?

Comment: denying is like locking everybody out. thats not what you want. just dont allow it and the user will be forced to authenticate first.

Comment: How do I "not allow it"?

Comment: by using the auth component and NOT calling Auth->allow().

Comment: Oh okay! I followed the tutorial and it seemed like that's what we were supposed to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `loginAction` variable in the $components declaration (controller or AppController) to specify a controller+action :

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'users'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

Comment: So, I'm clearly authenticating improperly, but how can I still get the proper page flow? Click a product -> Register -> Checkout? I can just have the Register action redirect them to checkout afterwards, but then I would have to change a little logic of the product page so that if they're logged in then it won't just go to the register page again. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You just laid it out.  In the product controller action, you check if user is logged in. If yes, show product page. If not, save the product to the cart/session, then call `$this->redirect('register')` to forward them to the register page. And as you stated, after registration, call something like `$this->redirect('checkout')` to redirect them to the checkout page.

Comment: Nice! One last question, is it a good idea to store the product name into the session in the register action and then clear it after the checkout?

Comment: That's fine. Cart contents are usually stored in the session. A session is not like a cookie which is stored on the client. Sessions are stored server-side so you can put whatever you like in there with minimal fear of tampering.

Comment: I really appreciate the help Costa! Thank you! I wish I could thank you more!